# Pass prop value down from login component to routes component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a login form setup using  and one particular value `props.values.userType` I need to pass down via props to my `index.js` file where I render all my routes.

So in my [`<Login>`](https://fy12t.codesandbox.io/login) component I have a `<RadioButtonGroup>` that renders the 3 types of users available

```
<RadioButtonGroup
 id="userType"
 label="User Type"
 value={values.userType}
 error={errors.userType}
 touched={touched.userType}
 onBlur={handleBlur}
>
```

From here the `userType` exists in `formik` as `props.values.userType`

I want to pass this prop value down to my `index.js` file that renders all my routes.

`index.js` below

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={FormikLoginForm} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin" component={AdminPage} />
      <Route path="/admin/change-password" component={ChangePassword} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

How can I achieve this?

[codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/logincomponent-fy12t)

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding your problem, you need to pass what to where from where?

Comment: I need to pass `props.values.userType` from my `<Login>` component down to one of the `<Routes>` in my `index.js` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `component` as a prop for each `<Route />`, you can use the `render` prop to pass props into the component you want to render on that route.

For example in your case, if your component was called `Login`:

```
<Route
  path='/login'
  render={(props) => <Login {...props} userType={props.values.userType} />}
/>
```

Or something similar depending on your use case.

Comment: I just stumbled across this solution here https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/, cheers!

Comment: No problem! You may not need to use {..props} depending on your situation/use case :)

Comment: I'm trying to use the value for a role based auth to render admin pages only when `userType === "admin"`, basically